# How to Use the lagrange multupliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the maxima and minima of $f(x,y,z,w)= x+y+z$ subject to the constraints $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $y^2+z^2+w^2=1$.

can someone help me start?

Comment: You have $f(x,y,z,w)$ formula with no $w$ in it. Is that what you meant to write?

Comment: @coffemath, I was wondering that as well, but I checked, and what I wrote is exactly the question posed.

Comment: Then as long as the first constraint is satisfied, there will automatically be $w$ making the second constraint satisfied, namely $w=\pm x.$ So unless $w$ is really to be viewed as a constant in the problem, it would seem the problem is just about max/min of $x+y+z$ on the sphere

Answer (score 1):

Let the first multiplier be $\lambda$ and second be $u$.

Then $1=2x\lambda=2y\lambda+2yu=2z\lambda+2zu$, $0=2wu$.

So $x={1\over 2\lambda}, y=z={1\over 2\lambda+2u}$

(1) $w=0$, then $y^2+z^2=1\implies x=0$ contradiction.

(2) $u=0$, then $x=y=z={1\over 2\lambda}$ and hence $\lambda={\sqrt{3}\over2}$

$f=x+y+z={3\over2\lambda}=\sqrt{3}$